# C++, error de Hola mundo

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::cout << "Hola mundo"; << end1;  


    return 0;

}
```

Y el error es el siguiente:

> using namespace std;

Comment: Tienes un `;` después del `"Hola mundo"`, ese seria el error de compilación que
me sale a mi. Puedes copiar todo el error que te salga? Con lo poco que has
colocado el error no tiene sentido

Comment: Diría que aparte de eso, el `endl` es un `end1` (acabado en 1)

Comment: el ";" del "hola mundo" no va, y el using namespace tambien, dado que estas siendo explicito con el "std::"

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hola Mundo!" << endl;
}
```

El error está en que debes quitar el punto y coma que pusiste poco antes de `endl` porque finalizas el comando prematuramente. También quité el `std::` porque no es necesario si ya lo declaraste al principio.

Comment: Nice, ahora los otros comentarios estan de mas, los voy borrando para no llenar
los comentarios con contenido irrelevante. Gracias por aclarar.